# If the complement of a subring is closed under multiplication, then the subring is integrally closed.

Tags: commutative-algebra, integral-dependence

> Let $A\subset B$ be rings, and suppose that $B\setminus A$ is closed under multiplication. Show that $A$ is integrally closed in $B$. (Atiyah and MacDonald,  *Introduction to Commutative Algebra*, Chapter 5, Exercise 7)

I tried localizing at $B\setminus A$, but this did not seem to work. Neither did a direct application of the definition of "integral dependence". Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you mean "$\,A\,$ int. closed in $\,B\,$"?

Comment: It also seems like $B\setminus A$ might contain zero, so one would wonder if localization would get you anywhere. Are you working with domains?

Comment: $A$ contains zero, so $B\setminus A$ doesn't! :-)

Comment: @DonAntonio; you are right, I have corrected the typo.

Comment: This is exercise 5.7 from Atiyah and MacDonald, CA.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take $x\in B$ which is integral over $A$ and write $x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+\cdots +a_n=0$ with $a_i\in A$ and $n$ the least possible. Then $x(x^{n-1}+a_1x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{n-1})=-a_n\in A$. If $x$ is not in $A$, then $ x^{n-1}+a_1x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{n-1}\in A$, contradiction.